# How can I pause between URL Get requests?

Tags: r, rcurl

I have a function that takes two arguments, assembles a URL, and submits a GET request.  I feed the function a list of arguments (a pair of arguments for each record), and everything comes back just fine.

However, I would like to be sure that I am only sending one request at a time.  The result come back so fast that I'm not sure if I'm hammering their server or not.

Here's what I've got (df is a dataframe with 25 rows, so I'm submitting 25 requests in this case):

```
 library(RCurl)

 block <- function(latty, longy){
             url <- paste0("http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=", latty, "&longitude=", longy)
             response <- getURL(url)
             blockID <- substr(sub(".*Block FIPS=\\\"","",response), 0, 15)
             return(blockID)
             Sys.sleep(0.25)
           }

 result <- do.call(block, list(latty=df$lat, longy=df$long))
```

When I run this script, is it flooding the server with requests, or is it stepping through them at the Sys.sleep rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Sys.sleep` after returning from the `block` function. However, I am not sure that it can be solved with `do.call`, since it passes all the arguments at the once. I would use `sapply` or other vectorized function instead. For example

```
sapply(1:nrow(df$long), block)
block <- function(i){
                 latty <- df$lat[i]
                 longy <- df$long[i]
                 Sys.sleep(0.25)
                 url <- paste0("http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2010/find?latitude=", latty, "&longitude=", longy)
                 response <- getURL(url)
                 substr(sub(".*Block FIPS=\\\"","",response), 0, 15)
               }
```

`sapply` will wait for each iteration to finish before starting another one, for example

```
> sapply(1:10, function(x) {Sys.sleep(1); print(Sys.time())})
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:28 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:29 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:30 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:31 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:32 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:33 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:34 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:35 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:36 PST"
[1] "2015-11-13 11:36:37 PST"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is my function call (do.call) submitting one pair of arguments at a time though?  That is, does it submit a pair, wait for the response, and then submit the next pair?

Comment: @user1252489 perhaps you should use `mapply` instead?

Comment: @Roman Tsegelskyi, thank you so much.  Your sapply example was a huge help.  Just what I was looking for!